# Output hosts from ansible inventory group to a template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I try to fill the ansible (jinja) template with a comma-separated list of all hosts in the group 'lan-msqservers'.

```
<add key="MessageBus:LanConnectionString" value="host=host1.fqdn,host2.fqdn,host3.fqdn;virtualHost=/;username=user;password=passwd;timeout=60" />
```

I tried:

```
host='{{ groups[lan-msqservers][0] }}','{{ groups[lan-msqservers][1]}}';

host=groups['lan-msqservers'][0]],groups['lan-msqservers'][1]];
```

Without success.

can anyone help?

Comment: i don't need a list like that. even not if it's joined by comma.
i want to read all hostsnames from ansible inventory and put it info this template.

Comment: the solution is:
host={% for host in groups['lan-msqservers'] %}{{ host }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}